# Bigquery extract hour from UTC timestamp

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I extrac the hour from a DATETIME() of the following format:

```
2019-05-03T04:20:11.853290
```

When I use the EXTRACT() function it simply returns all values 0:

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM '2019-05-03T04:20:11.853290')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DATETIME '2019-05-03T04:20:11.853290')
```

or

```
EXTRACT(HOUR FROM TIMESTAMP('2019-05-03T04:20:11.853290'))
```